# Firebase taking too long to fetch data ( javascript )

Tags: javascript, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
/*** Define all functions here (Query)! ***/
function get_all_loc(){ //get all locs in array
ref = database.ref('locs/');  //get from -- > locs in db
ref.on('value', gotData, errData);  // getData or error !
all_locs_arr = [] ; //empty array everytime button is clicked -> to show new query :P if db updated meanwhile ! silly :P
all_locs_str = ""; //empty str everytime button is clicked -> to show new query :P if db updated meanwhile ! silly :P
function gotData(data){
    all_locs_arr = data.val(); console.log(all_locs_arr); //firebase func to get data from db , storing it in all_loc_arr
    for(var loc_index=0; loc_index<all_locs_arr.length ; loc_index++){
        all_locs_str += "<li class='class_loc' loc-id='"+loc_index+"' >"+all_locs_arr[loc_index]+"</li>";
        //console.log(all_locs_str);// add all locs in string
    }
get_raw_matrix();
}function errData(data){
    console.log("db_error! locs !");
}
}
get_all_loc(); // call get_all_loc function to get all locations into array & str , early fetch
```

This is my function for querying data from firebase.

after , `all_locs_arr = data.val();` , i am doing `console.log(all_locs_arr)` ,
and for array (of length 10,000) , its taking more than 5 minutes to print on console.

Its an array of strings. the size of each string in the array is less than 10.

Why is fetching data so slow? Am I doing something wrong? Am I fetching too much of data?

I am not performing any search/sort, just fetching the entire data, still, it is slow .

Comment: I think I shouldn't fetch all the data, I should use `ref = database.ref('locs/' + something )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it, I was simply fetching a lot of data.

```
ref = database.ref('locs/')
```

The above line meant , i was fetching everthying in locs , that was 10k entries .

I changed it to `ref = database.ref('locs/' + some_variable)` 
It means i am fetching only required entry from locs .